# How do I tell BibTeX to print the 'pages' field for entries of type '@book'?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I want to cite a book. I got the following bibliographic information from MathSciNet:

```
@book {Brylinski,
AUTHOR = {Brylinski, Jean-Luc},
TITLE = {Loop spaces, characteristic classes and geometric
quantization},
SERIES = {Progress in Mathematics},
VOLUME = {107},
PUBLISHER = {Birkh\"{a}user Boston, Inc., Boston, MA},
YEAR = {1993},
PAGES = {xvi+300},
ISBN = {0-8176-3644-7},
MRCLASS = {57Rxx (18G50 55P35 58F06)},
MRNUMBER = {1197353},
MRREVIEWER = {Daniel S. Freed},
DOI = {10.1007/978-0-8176-4731-5},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4731-5},}
```

Unfortunately, the formatted bibliographic entry does not show the number of pages (stored in the entry's `pages` field). It comes out as

> Jean-Luc Brylinski. Loop spaces, characteristic classes and geometric quantization, volume 107 of Progress in Mathematics. Birkhäuser Boston, Inc., Boston, MA, 1993.

What changes should I make so that it also mentions the number of pages?

Minimal working example is

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\textheight 9.3in 
\textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout

% metadata

%\date{\today}

\title{****}
\author{***} 

\begin{document}
    %\today
\bibliography{****}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

---

Self contained MWE (requires a modern LaTeX installation for the `[overwrite]` feature)

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@book {Brylinski,
AUTHOR = {Brylinski, Jean-Luc},
TITLE = {Loop spaces, characteristic classes and geometric
quantization},
SERIES = {Progress in Mathematics},
VOLUME = {107},
PUBLISHER = {Birkh\"{a}user Boston, Inc., Boston, MA},
YEAR = {1993},
PAGES = {100-3010},
ISBN = {0-8176-3644-7},
MRCLASS = {57Rxx (18G50 55P35 58F06)},
MRNUMBER = {1197353},
MRREVIEWER = {Daniel S. Freed},
DOI = {10.1007/978-0-8176-4731-5},
URL = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4731-5},}
\end{filecontents}


%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\textheight 9.3in 
\textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout

% metadata

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliography{sample}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can make this a better example by including the bib entry in the example using the `filecontents` env to generate a bib file that can then be included in the `\bibliography` line. Then you have a truly self contained example. Besides this example will not print anything as nothing is cited

Comment: The `plain` style does not consider the `pages` field for `@book` types. To be honest. I've never seen that in a bibliography for a book. It is not particularly relevant for the reader

Comment: Which style do you suggest to consider page numbers for book types? @daleif

Comment: No idea, as mentioned I've never seen it specified and as a reader it would just be irrelevant data.

Comment: You could use the `note` field in the bibliography entry.

Comment: Are you committed to using the `plain` bib style, or would you be willing to consider a different bib style? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I have no preference for any style anything is fine :)

Comment: @daleif You said this minimal example is not sufficient. Can you please tell me what else to add? I do not know what is filecontents env mean..

Comment: There is no citations in it, bibtex only include what ever is cited. Perhaps add `\nocite{*}` this will cite _everything_

Comment: @daleif I have absolutely no idea what is going on here.. :) Please see if you can make any changes in the question to make it clearer :) Please

Comment: See my update, then a person wanting to help does not need to add or change _anything_ to help you. Your example did not have any `\cite` so once someone had filled in `\bibliography` they'd also have to add a `\cite` to the example, plus make a `.bib` file. This example as it all.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the edit. So, you think number of pages in a book is of no use when you cite. Then the question is, why would MathSciNet include it in the citation when it is not common..

Comment: Counter question: why would they include `MRNUMBER`? Why does some services include the entire abstract. Some may use it, some may not. That is all up to the style. Each bibstyle will for each entry type have a list of required fields, a list of optional fields (included if present, no error it is not present), the rest is ignored. So `plain` will ignore `PAGES` for `@book` (which to me seems fair), another style may choose to include it. It is all down to the separation of the content and the formatting.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - You should NEVER blindly trust the correctness of bibliographic information downloaded from somewhere on the 'net. For instance, the entry you downloaded improperly combines information about the book's publisher and the publisher's address in a single field. Likewise, just because the website provides a field -- say, `pages` -- does not mean that you must find blindly find a way to output that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `plain.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `plain-bookpages.bst`. (Do not edit an original, unrenamed file of your TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `plain-bookpages.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the file `plain-bookpages.bst`, find the BibTeX function `book`. In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 557.
- *Immediately before* this function, insert the following code chunk, which contains two BibTeX functions -- `bibinfo.check` and `format.book.pages`:

  ```
  FUNCTION {bibinfo.check}
  { swap$ duplicate$ missing$
      { pop$ pop$ "" }
      { duplicate$ empty$
          { swap$ pop$ }
          { swap$ pop$ }
        if$
      }
    if$
  }
  FUNCTION {format.book.pages}
  { pages "pages" bibinfo.check
    duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
      { " " * "pages" * }   
    if$
  }
  ```
- In the `book` function, find the following line:

  ```
        publisher "publisher" output.check
  ```

  *Immediately before* this line, insert the following line:

  ```
        format.book.pages output
  ```
- Save the file `plain-bookpages.bst` either in the folder that contains your main tex file(s) or in a folder that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably. If the preceding sentence sounds like gibberish to you, I recommend you choose the first option.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{plain-bookpages}` and perform a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

By the way, I think it's *wrong* that MathSciNet combines information about they entry's publisher and the publisher's address in a single field; it's better to keep track of separate `publisher` and `address` fields. I also think it's wrong of mathscinet to lowercase most words in the `title` field.

Here's the output of a full MWE (minimum working example) that employs the newly created `plain-bookpages` bib style:

[image]

And, for comparison, here's how the entry is formatted if the `plain` bibliography style is employed:

[image]

A final comment: I can't help but remark that there is a very good reason for why virtually all bibliography styles ever programmed are set up to *ignore* the `pages` field in entries of type `@book`. What's this reason, you may ask? Well, it's that the `pages` field in entries of type `@book` is pretty much guaranteed to be of no interest whatsoever to readers. Bibliographic information is supposed to help readers obtain copies of bibliographic entries of interest, either from a library (physical or electronic) or from a bookstore. That's why the `publisher` field *is* relevant for entries of type `@book`. The contents of the `pages` field, in comparison, serve no comparable purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@book{Brylinski,
    AUTHOR    = {Brylinski, Jean-Luc},
    TITLE     = {Loop Spaces, Characteristic Classes and Geometric Quantization},
    SERIES    = {Progress in Mathematics},
    VOLUME    = {107},
    PUBLISHER = {Birkh{\"a}user},
    address   = {Boston~MA},
    YEAR      = {1993},
    PAGES     = {xvi+300},
    ISBN      = {0-8176-3644-7},
    MRCLASS   = {57Rxx (18G50 55P35 58F06)},
    MRNUMBER  = {1197353},
    MRREVIEWER= {Daniel S. Freed},
    DOI       = {10.1007/978-0-8176-4731-5},
    URL       = {https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-8176-4731-5},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{plain-bookpages}

\begin{document}
\nocite{Brylinski}
\raggedright
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You... :) :)